# Fragmented TCP message in Python

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I have an application which read **live** SIP Packets and decode information in real time.
when packet is small UDP/TCP is able to get the information, but when packet is large, it arrives in different segments:
The following is an extract from Wireshark:

```
3 Reassembled TCP Segments (3331 bytes): #1(1448), #3(1448), #5(435)
Frame: 1, payload: 0-1447 (1448 bytes)
Frame: 3, payload: 1448-2895 (1448 bytes)
Frame: 5, payload: 2896-3330 (435 bytes)
Segment count: 3
Reassembled TCP length: 3331
```

My application believes there is a new SIP Packet for each fragment and fails to decode info.
How can I do this? I need to read the packet, assemble all sip message if fragmented and pass the info to my control module. This is my current code:

```
s = socket.socket( socket.AF_PACKET , socket.SOCK_RAW , socket.ntohs(0x0003))

while (True):
 packet = s.recvfrom(65565) 
        #packet string from tuple
        packet = packet[0] 
        #parse ethernet header
        eth_length = 14

        eth_header = packet[:eth_length]
        eth = unpack('!6s6sH' , eth_header)
        eth_protocol = socket.ntohs(eth[2])


if eth_protocol == 8 :
            #Parse IP header
            #take first 20 characters for the ip header
            ip_header = packet[eth_length:20+eth_length]

            #now unpack them :)
            iph = unpack('!BBHHHBBH4s4s' , ip_header)

            version_ihl = iph[0]
            version = version_ihl >> 4
            ihl = version_ihl & 0xF

            iph_length = ihl * 4

            ttl = iph[5]
            protocol = iph[6]
            s_addr = socket.inet_ntoa(iph[8]);
            d_addr = socket.inet_ntoa(iph[9]);


            #TCP protocol

            if protocol == 6 :
                t = iph_length + eth_length
                tcp_header = packet[t:t+20]

                #now unpack them :)
                tcph = unpack('!HHLLBBHHH' , tcp_header)

                source_port = tcph[0]
                dest_port = tcph[1]
                sequence = tcph[2]
                acknowledgement = tcph[3]
                doff_reserved = tcph[4]
                tcph_length = doff_reserved >> 4

                if dest_port == sipLocatorConfig.SIP_PORT:   
                    print               
                    logging.info("------------------------------------------------------SIP Packet detected------------------------------------------------------")
                    h_size = eth_length + iph_length + tcph_length * 4
                    data_size = len(packet) - h_size
                    #get data from the packet
                    data = packet[h_size:] 

                    ipInfo = {}
                    ipInfo['protocol'] = protocol
                    ipInfo['s_addr'] = str(s_addr)
                    ipInfo['source_port'] = source_port
                    ipInfo['d_addr'] = str(d_addr)
                    ipInfo['dest_port'] = dest_port
                    processSipPacket(data,ipInfo)
```

Comment: TCP can only transfer messages of one byte.  Anything more requires a protocol on top of that streaming service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what I wrote bufsock for:
http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/bufsock.html

It allows you to say "give me all the data until the next null" or "give me the next 64 bytes" and similar things.  It deals intelligently with fragmented and aggregated packets.

Unlike many such tools, it does not require that you have bufsock at both the producer and the consumer - you can use it fine on one end and not the other.  It is a little bit like stdio for sockets, in python.

It works on CPython 2.x, CPython 3.x, Pypy, Pypy3 (which is still beta at this time) and Jython.